# Which is the standard posix way:double \  or single \  in regex  expression?

Tags: python, r, shell, posix

to get file which ended in . ,you can do :
1.R

```
list.files(path='/home/test', all.files=TRUE, pattern="\\.$")
```

or

```
list.files(path='/home/test', all.files=TRUE, pattern=".+\\.$")
```

must double \ in R  ,can  use  neither `.+\.$`  nor `\.$`

2.python

```
import os
import re
for   root,   dirs,   files   in   os.walk("/home/test"):
    for file in files:
        if re.search(".+\.$",file):
            print file
```

can  either  use  `.+\\.$`   or `\.$` or `\\.$` in python.

3.shell

```
find /home/test  -regex  ".+\.$"
```

can use   ".+\.$"  too in shell

I want to know
1.which is the posix way between `.+\\.$`  and `.+\.$`  ?
2.why i can't use `find /home/test  -regex  "\.$"`  in shell?

Comment: Wow, you changed you question - don't do that, ask new questions. But: please read help files etc. before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between what you type and what a regex engine sees in the end.

There could be two questions:

- what flavor of regex does my tool (R, Python, find) understand?

  For example, if you use Python; you should ask what syntax does `re` module support?
- how do I input a regex?

  For example, `".+\.$"` in `find -regex  ".+\.$"` is interpreted by a shell first. So the question becomes how does your shell interpret `".+\.$"`? Once you've answered it you could ask what regex syntax does `find` support?

[POSIX regexes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) expect a single backslash in the `\.` pattern (to match a literal dot) but to input it in a particular environment you might require two backslashes e.g., in Python `"\\."` and `r"\."` are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Did you even read `?regexp`? It's written there. From what I see 'POSIX 1003.2' regular expressions are used.